# Press and hold for accents does not work everytime

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

I am a German User, but i am using a US Keyboard and the US Extended Keyboard Layout. Sometimes I need to use German Umlauts, and I usually rely on the "press and hold for accented characters" feature of OS X.

However, this is not always available. I cant seem to find a pattern in this behavior. Sometimes I log in, and it works flawlessly, sometimes it doesn't work at all and just repeats the character I press for a long time.

I switched to different keyboard layouts (US, US Extended, US International PC) and different "Preferred Languages" in the "Language and Region" settings.

I also tried the `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true` setting, but also no luck.

I have the same problem on different Macs; at work and at home.

How do I configure this feature correctly?

Answer (score 10):

When it stops working, does `ps -ef|grep PressAndHold` include a line for `/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/MacOS/PressAndHold`? If it doesn't, try to run `open -a PressAndHold`. Or if it does, `killall PressAndHold;open -a PressAndHold` might also be worth a shot.

You could also try to delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist`. Normally `defaults read com.apple.HIToolbox` should show `com.apple.PressAndHold` under `AppleEnabledInputSources` and `AppleSelectedInputSources`.

Comment: Stopped working randomly, `PressAndHold` was present in my `ps` listing, had to `killall PressAndHold;open -a PressAndHold` to get it back. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The option/alt + key combinations should be more reliable once you learn them. For example `alt + s` types ß and `alt + u` followed by a vowel types the umlauted vowel äëïöü.

P.S. Thanks for pointing out the press and hold technique that's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. The press and hold had stopped working in all programs. I followed the instructions below and it worked again

A way to make sure it is enabled is: open Terminal, from Applications, Utilities, then in the Terminal window type, exactly,

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

press Enter and finally quit Terminal

The key should now do the accents.

Comment: This worked for me in addition to the `open -a PressAndHold` command.  Not sure why it had been voted down.

Comment: For some reason, I had to remove the -g flag in order to get it working on Mojave. `defaults write ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not wedded to using Press and Hold, I‘ve been using this https://hci.rwth-aachen.de/usgermankeyboard for my trusty model M since years.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:  I'm on OS 10.9.2 and press and hold is not working for me at the moment.  If I type:

```
defaults read -g
```

I get:

```
{
AppleAntiAliasingThreshold = 4;
AppleAquaColorVariant = 6;
AppleEnableMenuBarTransparency = 0;
AppleLanguages =     (
    en,
    fi,
    fr,
    de,
    "zh-Hans",
    "zh-Hant",
    ja,
    es,
    it,
    nl,
    ko,
    pt,
    "pt-PT",
    da,
    nb,
    sv,
    ru,
    pl,
    tr,
    ar,
    th,
    cs,
    hu,
    ca,
    hr,
    el,
    he,
    ro,
    sk,
    uk,
    id,
    ms,
    vi
);
AppleLocale = "en_GB";
AppleMiniaturizeOnDoubleClick = 0;
AppleUserLanguages = 1;
InitialKeyRepeat = 68;
KeyRepeat = 6;
NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled = 1;
NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = 1;
NSAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled = 1;
NSNavPanelFileLastListModeForOpenModeKey = 1;
NSNavPanelFileLastListModeForSaveModeKey = 1;
NSNavPanelFileListModeForOpenMode2 = 1;
NSNavPanelFileListModeForSaveMode2 = 1;
NSNavPanelSidebarKeyForOpen =     (
);
NSNavPanelSidebarKeyForSave =     (
);
NSNavRecentPlaces =     (
    "~/Fede/Work/Parkinson/EPIC4PD/H2020",
    "~/Desktop/Archival",
    "~/Fede/Work/QTL/Rana-temporaria/Fede-new",
    "~/Fede/Cloud",
    "~/Fede/Cloud/OneDrive"
);
NSPreferredWebServices =     {
    NSWebServicesProviderWebSearch =         {
        NSDefaultDisplayName = Google;
        NSProviderIdentifier = "com.google.www";
    };
};
NSTableViewDefaultSizeMode = 1;
NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems =     (
);
NavPanelFileListModeForOpenMode = 1;
NavPanelFileListModeForSaveMode = 1;
WebAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled = 1;
"com.apple.keyboard.fnState" = 1;
"com.apple.springing.delay" = "0.5";
"com.apple.springing.enabled" = 1;
```

}

i.e I am not getting `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` in the first place.  in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` I have the correct instances of `com.apple.PressAndHold`, but I noticed a file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` which does not have `com.apple.PressAndHold`.  One guess is that if `com.apple.PressAndHold` were to be added there press and hold might work...

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't work until I restart the application, which was Pages, in my case.